# flying from US to Canada with a New York state license?

Tags: air-travel, canada, us-citizens, id

I have a regular New York state license. can I fly from New York to Canada with my license as ID?

Answer (score 5):

A drivers license is insufficent when arriving in Canada by air.

[This webpage](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/international-travel/International-Travel-Country-Information-Pages/Canada.html) from the US government about entering Canada states:

> Entry into Canada: Canadian law requires that all persons entering Canada carry proof of citizenship and identity. A valid U.S. passport, passport card, or NEXUS card satisfies these requirements for U.S. citizens.

However, when arriving by land, [this page](https://www.canadaduientrylaw.com/enhanced-drivers-license.php) (about a DUI conviction) says

> Americans with an Enhanced Identification Card (EIC) or Enhanced Drivers License (EDL) from Washington State, Minnesota, South Dakota, Michigan, New York, or Vermont can be allowed to travel to Canada without a Passport. Enhanced Driver's Licenses are only valid for land and marine crossings, however, so you will **not be able to fly to Canada** with it as your only form of identification.

Comment: Anyway the asker of this question does not have an enhanced license.  "Proof of citizenship and identity" has traditionally included a driver's license plus a birth certificate or naturalization certificate, but Canada has been rewording their public information to make that increasingly obscure in recent years, and I believe they are officially putting an end to the possibility sometime soon if they haven't already.  Even if Canada would accept it, though, the US and the airline might not.